# Recompile directive template in AngularJS

Tags: templates, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add authentication capabilities to my app by providing a service `auth` with `login` and `logout` methods and a `loggedIn` property (once I get it to work, this will actually be the user object, but now it's just a boolean for simplicity) and a `login` directive, which displays either an inline login form or a logout button, depending on the value of the `loggedIn` variable.

Simple auth implementation:

```
app.factory 'auth', ($log) ->
  {
    loggedIn: false
    login: (username, password) ->
      $log.log "Login: #{username}, #{password}"
      if username is "a" and password is "b"
        @loggedIn = true
    logout: ->
      @loggedIn = false
  }
```

(Obviously, once I get this to work, the login will be done through REST! This is just for convenience, and all the app logic resides on the server, which uses a traditional session)

I'm having trouble with the directive. I know that I can use `template` or `templateUrl` to choose a template statically, but how do I replace the current template with a new `$compile`d one?

```
app.directive "login", ($compile) ->
    restrict: "E"
    templateUrl: "/login.html"
    scope: { }
    controller: ($scope, $element, $log, auth) ->
      $scope.auth = auth
      $scope.$watch 'auth.loggedIn', (newVal, oldVal) ->
        $log.log "Done: #{newVal} <- #{oldVal}"
        # here I should switch to the other template if newVal != oldVal
```

I know I could probably get the root element of the template, remove the old nodes and add the new ones, but I am hoping there is a more "declarative" way to do this in angular, without doing any DOM operations.

Comment: i got it to work by following the example here: http://jsbin.com/unidoy/1/edit. replace the element using $element and then call $compile on the new subtree. However, I don't know if there is any extra precaution to be taken when replacing the old nodes with the new ones, in terms of bindings/watchers still alive on the old nodes. also, while the DOM manipulation logic here is minimal, technically I'm still manipulating the DOM :-)

Comment: do you know replace:true property?

Comment: that doesn't seem to be related. it simply removes the `login` node when attaching the compiled template to the DOM. It has nothing to do with how compiling a new string is affected, and it doesn't seem you can pass this to $compile, but only as a directive definition option.

Comment: Strugling with the same thing. I think the answer is a link function which has access to scope, and can then $watch the change in your variable. Check this answer, then adapt. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19122382/162070